# "He got married" vs "He got marriage"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Normally I used to hear people say "he got **married**" but I saw someone who said "He got **marriage** to her". Are both equal?

Comment: It should be He got married to her. He *got* ***marriage*** *to her* is grammatically wrong.

Comment: Why couldn't you answer this with a dictionary?

Comment: There's a fairly common mistake of yours that I see in your posts: you don't "see" someone "say", but you "hear" someone "say" something. Otherwise, you can state that you *read* it somewhere. Always a good idea to say "where" you read something.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. Is it not possible to *see* someone who said it? I didn't say that I saw someone says (even it's also possible) but I said that I saw someone WHO said. Isn't it?

Comment: You can see someone, and you can see someone talking, but you "hear" or "overhear" what they say. You *hear* words, phrases, rumours, brief exclamations. You "listen" to a discussion, a speech, a teacher, the news etc.

Comment: PS to "ping" someone you need to preface their username with @ e.g @Mari-Lou A

Comment: He was married to her or he married her.

Answer (score 2):

No. Your sentence

> He got **marriage** to her.

is ungrammatical in English if used to mean "He got married to her." It could be grammatical if your meaning were that "he" somehow conveyed the concept or essence of marriage across some physical or intellectual distance to "her" ... but that is almost certainly not your meaning, and in any case it would still be problematic and confusing even if it were.

Comment: Yeaaaah, even that benefit-of-the-doubt interpretation would be a huge stretch. ;)